# Как сделать так, чтобы сайт занимал всю ширину экрана всегда при ширине контейнеров 1920 пикселей?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, responsive, viewport

Допустим у нас есть сайт сверстанный для монитора 1920 пикселей. Как сделать так, чтобы на разных разрешениях (мобильный, планшет, ноутбук) он занимал 100% ширины экрана. То есть как бы адаптивности не будет в таком случае, сайт просто ресайзится и подгоняется под ширину экрана, а все элементы сжимаются. Вроде такую картинку можно наблюдать на старых сайтах, но вот как это реализовать - не знаю, поскольку сверстал с использованием bootstrap 4, мета тег viewport убрал, поставил для container - ширину 1920 пикселей фиксированную. Но вот на разных девайсах появляется скролл, а мне нужно чтобы сайт занимал 100% ширину девайса, за счет уменьшения элементов. Думаю вы поняли, что я хочу. Очень нужна помощь в этом вопросе. Спасибо!

Comment: Пробовал еще такую вещь <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920"> - не помогает.

Comment: Вы совсем не то написали. Попробуйте <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Шапке вашей задайте ширину в 100% просто

Comment: `html {height:200%; transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);}` - попробуйте пойти от этого.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте в `head` тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Также убери со всех тегов фиксированную ширину - используйте только `max-width` или же процентные значения.

А вообще - адаптивный/резиновый сайт не делается за два свойства. Нужно изначально правильно продумывать архитектуру.